# MSVS - WPF - How do I make ProjectName.csproj build App.xaml and App.xaml.cs last?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, visual-studio-2019, csproj

My WPF project has App.xaml require other pieces of project code to be built before it gets built. Despite App.xaml's dependency on those classes and xaml files, Visual Studio wants to build it first before anything else can get built.

For further information, here's the dependencies that are not getting addressed when I build from scratch.

XAML namespaces:

```
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Views"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:ProjectName.ViewModels"
```

XAML namespace implementations:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

HomeViewModel is a class in ...ViewModels.

HomeView is a class and XAML file in ...Views.

I know that the .csproj build order is the main problem, because I built the solution omitting the datatemplates and got no errors, and when I built after putting them back in I am still fine.

But when I cleaned the solution and rebuilt, I get errors up the wazoo!

I am making an MVVM application and I absolutely need App.xaml to be built last, as otherwise it would be difficult to make further iterations (as in, more Views / ViewModels) to this project.

How do I alter the .csproj files so that this happens?

I'm using MS Visual Studio Community 2019.

Also, I tried looking through build targets and overriding them but I can't figure out how to make it so that certain pieces of source code get built last.

Additional context:

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ProjectName.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName;assembly=ProjectName"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:ProjectName.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MainViewModel}">
            <views:MainView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:NGViewModel}">
            <views:NGView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
            <views:HomeView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!---->
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

HomeView.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ProjectName.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for HomeView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HomeView : UserControl
    {
        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectName.Views.HomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Black">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ProjectName.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

BaseViewModel.cs (bonus - parent class of HomeViewModel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Prototype7022.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to alter the project files, just declare your classes correctly in the desired namespaces. We can't help if you do not show us the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I already had those classes in the desired namespaces. I added the code you wanted to see with the respective namespaces already added in.

Comment: Why is there `;assembly=ProjectName` on the `local` namespace declaration in App.xaml? Do you have multiple projects?

Comment: Honestly, it's an artifact of me trying to solve the problem of the project not building properly.